# html mouse over event, can't show dialog

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to show a tooltip based on mouse over event . I have tried this code, but failed, nothing will show up.

Please advise.

```
<img onmouseover="showLongText();" BORDER=0 height=15 width=15 src="images/pick-button.gif"/>
<div id="longTextDiv" style="display:none;">
ddd
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showLongText(className, fldName, objId){   
    var longTextDiv = $("#longTextDiv");
    //alert(longTextDiv);
    longTextDiv.style.leftPos += 10;
    longTextDiv.style.posLeft = event.clientX;
    longTextDiv.style.posTop = event.clientY;
    longTextDiv.style.display = "";
    longTextDiv.setCapture();           
}
</script>
```

Comment: yes. Does JQuery have some plugin ?

Comment: I asked only because your question wasn't tagged with jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using jQuery. You should use

```
$("img").hover(function(e) {
    var longTextDiv = $("#longTextDiv");
    //alert(longTextDiv);
    longTextDiv.css({
       left : e.pageX,
       top : e.pageY, 
       display : "block"
    });
    longTextDiv.setCapture();           
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not supplying the necessary parameters to the function onmouseover... Change the functio definition to this:

`function showLongText(){`